# Cloud storage you pick for small, many files interchangeable between 2 machines?

Tags: java, cloud, storage

Right now. I have my personal, MBP, and my office laptop, Lenovo E460 (win10). What is your choice for small but *so many* files. I am Java programmer.

I am tried of using Git.

Comment: Hello. Can you explain us what would you like to do?

Comment: I just want to ask how move your workspace around smoothly such as if your day job require you to use 1 machine but another 1 is at yr home

Comment: And you want to synchronise your files only or all your working environment?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Dont know why I was not says that in the first place

Comment: Simplest option would be to work directly in the cloud: Amazon workspaces or build a VM or use cloud 9 https://c9.io/pricing